# Updating DOM according to Firebase Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I want to update my DOM element everytime the value on the Firebase changes. I've seen that `Angularfire` handles three-way data binding, but from what I understood it only works if you take elements from `$firebaseArray` directly from the DOM.

What I have is an Element on the DOM (chart) that depends on some of the data on a `$firebaseArray`, but my element gets the data from a function instead of directly from the `$firebaseArray`. That means I have to do some pre-processing on the `$firebaseArray` before my element can use it.

This is what I have:

```
<pie-chart ng-repeat="chart in myCtrl.charts"
           data="chart.data"
           options="chart.options"></pie-chart>
```

This is my controller:

```
function MyCtrl($firebaseArray) {
  let myRef = new Firebase(refUrl);
  let chartsFirebase = $firebaseArray(myRef);

  let getCharts = function() {
    let charts = [];
    distanceGoals.$loaded().then(function() {
      // push some things from chartsFirebase on the charts array
      charts.push({
        options: { ... },
        data: [ ... ] 
      }); 
    }
    return charts;
  }

  this.charts = getCharts();
}
```

Turns out that in this way `this.charts` is only updated one time, after modifications on the data in Firebase I have to refresh the browser.

- Has anyone an idea of what I could do to achieve this behavior?

Comment: As the docs and a couple dozen question I've answered here on Stack Overflow indicate, if you're using $loaded for anything but debugging, you're probably doing it wrong and probably want to use $extend. (I authored the code for $loaded and $extend).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a child-changed event listener to your ref like this:

```
// Get a reference to our posts
var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts");
// Get the data on a post that has changed
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
  var changedPost = snapshot.val();
  console.log("The updated post title is " + changedPost.title);
});
```

This will get called everytime something changes in the location you put the listener on.
For more info take a look at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html and https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html.

Answer (score 1):

From the [AngularFire documentation on `$loaded()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-loaded)(emphasis mine):

> Returns a promise which is resolved when the **initial** array data has been downloaded from the database.

That explains the behavior you're seeing.

To solve this, you should extend the `$firebaseArray` as documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html#section-firebasearray

Some related questions:

- [AngularFire extending the service issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443066/angularfire-extending-the-service-issue)
- [Joining data between paths based on id using AngularFire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299972/joining-data-between-paths-based-on-id-using-angularfire/30311967#30311967) (includes a full example by the author of AngularFire)